# StackPanel not showing up when running UWP app (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, uwp

I am taking my first steps into UWP app development as I'm tired of any non-web development I do (e.g. WinForms) looking like something from 1995 no matter how I try to pretty it up.

I have been mucking around and produced using the designer, a page with an image, and a stackpanel filled with buttons. The designer view shows the stackpanel fine

[image]

And this is my XAML

```
<Page
    x:Class="TestBed.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestBed"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid Margin="48,10,0,0">
        <Image Source="/Assets/briefcase-1.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="413,220,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="200,86,1113,247" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <Button Content="Button" CanDrag="True" FontWeight="Bold" AllowDrop="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

However, when I run the app, the stackpanel doesn't show up (nor do any of the buttons inside it). I'm stumped. I tried setting the stackpanel "To Front" in terms of order, but no dice. Clearly my novice skills are showing.

Help?

Comment: do you have " this.InitializeComponent(); " statement in its page class constructor?

Comment: I will check (not in front of code at the second) but is that something that needs to be added for every widget/component you add to the UI? It would seem like something that should be added automatically? (E.g. there are other components I can see, like the image box)

Comment: Yes, initialize statement is automatically added. But I had worried that you edited it. But you said you didn’t. Then I think the answer is quiet clear, but not sure for your specific case. In grid tag, all element are settled down in left top corner that grid. So if you want to place items correctly, there are two ways. real easy one is change “grid” tag to stackpanel. And second one is following  daniel’s answer. And if you want to set margin depends on windows, use daniel’s answer. And i also prefer use second one

Comment: My guess , you put too big value to margin of stackpanel.

Answer (score 1):

It may be because you are setting the position of your controls with the `margin` attribute.

Try to read a bit into the different layout types like `Grid` `StackPanel` or `RelativePanel`.

A good introduction can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/layout-panels).

Just a basic thing you can do is something like this:

```
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rowdefinition Height="*"> //The * just fills in the remaining Screen space.
    <Rowdefinition Height="500"> //This Row is 500px high
    <Rowdefinition Height="*"> //Fills the rest of the screen (same as first row)
<Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Height="*">
    <ColumnDefinition Height="500">
    <ColumnDefinition Height="2*"> //Using 2* fills double the screen as *
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"> //Row and Column are 0-indexed
    //Elements to stack go in here
</StackPanel>
```

If you need more info or a bit more detailed example just tell me. I just have to wait until I'm home to have acces to UWP code.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
Margin="200,86,1113,247"
```

The designer things the target device has far more pixels than the actual device its running on. Dont forget these are 'effective pixels' so just because your screen may be 4k doesnt mean its 4000 pixels wide in UWP terminology.

Try here for more info

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/basics/design-and-ui-intro#effective-pixels-and-scaling

To fix this in your page XAML you need to specify the width and height of the design surface (d:DesignHeight="..." d:DesignWidth="...") - like this:

```
<Page
    x:Class="TestBed.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestBed"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
```

Comment: Thanks Dean. How do I figure out the design height and width of the surface pro (Microsoft tablet). I've Googled but can't seem to find anything (unless design height/width is literally just pixels? As in resolution? But it seems unlikely due to so much reference to effective pixels..)

Answer (score 1):

there are some editable code I'm splitting with "<--((**))-->" :

```
<Grid Margin="48,10,0,0" >
        <Image Source="/Assets/briefcase-1.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="413,220,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" <--((Margin="200,86,1113,247"))--> HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <Button Content="Button" CanDrag="True" FontWeight="Bold" AllowDrop="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

## YOUR PROBLEM

you are designing (developing) resolution is bigger than target device (window)

try this:

```
<Grid Margin="48,10,0,0" >
        <Image Source="/Assets/briefcase-1.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="413,220,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <Button Content="Button" CanDrag="True" FontWeight="Bold" AllowDrop="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```